# how to understand the chi square contingency table

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, chi-squared

I have few categorical features:

```
['Gender',
 'Married',
 'Dependents',
 'Education',
 'Self_Employed',
 'Property_Area']

from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
chi2, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency((pd.crosstab(df.Gender, df.Married).values))
print (f'Chi-square Statistic : {chi2} ,p-value: {p}')
```

#### output:

```
Chi-square Statistic : 79.63562874824729 ,p-value: 4.502328957824834e-19
```

How can I know if the features are independent from each other from these statistics?

I am trying to build a classification model so I just wanted to know are these categorical columns useful for predicting my target variable.

Comment: Sounds like more question for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Contingency tables** are used in statistics to summarize the relationship between several *categorical* variables.

In your example, The Contingency table between the two variables `Gender`and `Married` is a *Frequency* table of these variables presented simultaneously.

A **chi-squared test** conducted on a contingency table can test whether or not a ***relationship exists*** between variables. These effects are defined as relationships between rows and columns.

---

[scipy.stats.chi2_contingency](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html) computes -*by default*- [Pearson’s chi-squared statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test).

Moreover,we are interested in the [`Sig(2-Tailed)`](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/sig2-tailed-interpreting-results/) which is the p-value in your example.

The **p-valu**e is the evidence against a *null hypothesis*. The *smaller* the p-value, the *strong* the evidence that you should *reject* the null hypothesis.

And the null hypothesis in your case is the *dependence* of the observed frequencies in the contingency table.

---

Choosing Significant Level -*alpha* as **5%**; your **p-value** is `4.502328957824834e-19` is much less than `.05` indicating that the rows and columns of the contingency table are ***independent***. Generally this means that it is worthwhile to interpret the cells in the contingency table.

In this particular case it means that being *Male* or *Female* (i.e. Gender) is ***not*** distributed similarly across the different levels of *Marital Status* (i.e. Married, Not-Married).

So, being married may be the status of one gender more than the other!

---

### Update

According to your comment, I see you have some doubts about this test.

This test basically tells you if the relationship between variables is **Significant** (i.e. may represent the population) or came by **chance**!

So if you have high level of Significance (high p-value), that means there's a significant dependency between the variables!

Now, if `Gender` and `Married` are both features in your model, that may lead to over-fitting and features redundancy. Then, you may want to choose one of them.

But if `Gender` or `Married` is the dependent variable (like `y`), then it's good they have significant relationship.

Extra bonus:
Sometimes one of the features become *temporarily* a dependent variable during [Data Imputation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_(statistics)) (when you have missing values).

Comment: So if p is below .05 then it is independent variable. So my question is I am trying to predict a target variable (classification model) and I want to know if these categorical columns will be useful for predicting the target or should I drop the column? Is it good to have features which has relation between them for my model?

Comment: Highly correlated variables mean that adding both to your model doesn't really add much more information than adding either individually. Ideally, every feature for your model will be fully independent. In practice, you usually have to accept a certain amount of correlation in your features. See: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24452/in-supervised-learning-why-is-it-bad-to-have-correlated-features

Comment: Thanks @Chris for the info. :)